# Extracting WhatsApp messages from a Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a Phonegap app that will require pulling all the messages from a specific contact in WhatsApp.

So far I've found this guide: [link](http://geeknizer.com/read-extract-whatsapp-messages-android-iphone-blackberry/)

And I also read something about WhatsAPI but I have no idea how I'd use that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

I also found this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=24603294

Not sure what to do with it though.

Comment: Have you started with anything? Both links you provide are for running on a PC, not in an App. So what you have to do is find out what the script is doing (whatsapp_xtract.py) and then redo the same in an Android App.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the data is encrypted. So you need to know how the data is encrypted, then you can try to decrypt the data.